# Automating pg_dump by inserting user password automatically

Tags: postgresql, powershell, shell, command-line, pg-dump

So I am trying to automate a powerbi database back-up using `pg_dump -d powerbi -h HOST -U USER -n SCHEMA_NAME > dump.sql`

When running this on the command line, I am prompted to enter a password where a back-up promptly follows. The resulting dump.sql file is created after a few seconds and is around 60MB in size.

Now, I want to automate this as I want to schedule this task as a monthly task. Automating it means that I have to enter the password automatically.

I am aware that `PGPASSWORD = 'my_password'`  is a way of automatically assigning the password. However, when I run `PGPASSWORD = 'my_password' pg_dump -d powerbi -h HOST -U USER -n SCHEMA_NAME > dump.sql`

OR `SET PGPASSWORD = 'my_password' pg_dump -d powerbi -h HOST -U USER -n SCHEMA_NAME > dump.sql` the command executed but an empty dump.sql file is produced.

I tried also using `SET PGPASSFILE = "C:\postgresql\pgpass.conf"` but I obtain the same result.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how I could actually generate a meaningful back-up file when using `PGPASSWORD`

Comment: Why not use `pgpass.conf` per [pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgpass.html)?

Comment: When I run your 2nd given command, I get "'PGPASSWORD' is not recognized as an internal or external command".  Your 3rd one doesn't execute the pg_dump command at all when I do it. Presumably it is SET, not the pg_dump, which creates the empty file.  Your problem seems to be that you don't know how to use the Windows command shell (Neither do I).  You should probably tag your question as being about that.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I tried using a pgpass, but I obtain the same results

Comment: @jjanes I guess you're correct on my lack of command shell skills :-) I just tried to follow other solutions on stack-overflow where `PGPASSWORD` or `SET PGPASSWORD` worked seamlessly for other people

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't set a variable 'inline' the way you can with bash.  You have to set it as a separate command on its own line.  Also, you can't have spaces around the equal sign, and can't use single quotes around the value.  (Or you could use the GUI features to set it permanently.)

Comment: What you did was `SET PGPASSFILE = "C:\postgresql\pgpass.conf" `. Follow the instructions in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I ended up having it work by running command `SET PGPASSWORD='my_password'` first (with no spaces as @jjanes indicated).

Then I ran the the `pg_dump -d powerbi -h HOST -U USER -n SCHEMA_NAME > dump.sql` once environment variable has been set.

Thanks for the help